# Redirecting to an URL based on parameter taken from an Event

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript where I pass an event as a parameter on a click of a button and the script has to take the respective Id of the event, which I would then use to redirect to another page. The Code is as follows:

```js
function eventClick(e)
{ var Id = e.TaskId;
document.location='../Task/Assignedtask?taskId=' + Id;  
}
```

Although it raise an alert with the TaskId of that respective Event, but it does not redirect to the page that is intended.
I have tried href and window.location, still the alert window comes up with the taskId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `document.location.href` - "href" being the part that seems to be missing in your code.